# HTML Checkbox Alignment

Tags: html, checkbox, alignment

Test Page URL: http://www.guygar.com/inception/ultra/indexCopy.html

I am new to this and searching SO I found the following solution for alignment between text and Checkbox:

```
<div style="border-bottom:1px solid black; padding:4px; background-color:#003b5a;">
     <span style="font-weight:bold;">Back to the Roots</span>
     <form>
     <input type="checkbox" value="header" style="float:right; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -15px;" />
      <label></label>
      </form>
</div>
```

While this works in IE9, it does not work in Chrome or Firefox.

Could you please help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain where you are trying to align this?

Comment: I would like the text and the checkbox vertically in the middle of the <div>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your div `position:relative;` then you could make your input `position:absolute;top:5px; right:0;`

Comment: Wait! not working in FireFox. In FF the checkbox just a tad too high i.e. not centered. I have uploaded the new file and you can see it for yourself.

Comment: Works in IE9, Chrome and Safari! I am confused!

Comment: It was my fault, had to tweak several CSS to get it working in all the browsers. Thank you so much.